# Bypass mysql error if column does not exist

Tags: mysql

I am working on a mysql procedure that I can run on all of my client environments however I am running into one issue. Some of my clients have a particular column on the database and others do not.

I am trying to use update ignore but I still get an error if the column doesnt exist.

I know I can query information schema for a count where that column exists, but I'm wondering if there is a more simplistic way to achieve this.

```
update ignore table1 set columnA = null;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'columnA' in 'field list'
```

Comment: `UPDATE IGNORE` just ignores duplicate unique key errors, it doesn't ignore all errors. I don't think there's a way to ignore this error automatically.

Comment: This optional column design seems like it would be a real mess. How does the rest of your application deal with it?

Comment: Checking `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` seems like the only real solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

First solution: Check first if the column exists.

```
SELECT t.table_name, (c.column_name IS NULL) AS columnA_present
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c
  ON t.table_name = c.table_name and c.column_name = 'columnA'
WHERE t.table_name = 'table1';
```

Second solution: Run the UPDATE and catch the error. Check if the error is 1054. If so, then skip it. If not, then it's some other error so report it.